# Django - Model field for user groups

Tags: django, django-admin

I have model called `PM` to create `Private Message objects`. which is:

```
class Pm(models.Model):

    """
    Messaging System
    """
    subject = models.CharField(verbose_name='Message Subject',
                               max_length=50, blank=False)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Message Content',
                               max_length=1000, blank=False)
    to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False,
                           blank=False,verbose_name='Target',
                           related_name='target')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               blank=False,verbose_name='Sender',
                               null=False,
                               related_name='source')
```

i can create a message to single user. If i change `to` field into a `Many2Many` field, then i can create this message for multiple users.

But what i want is to create this message for some user groups. There should be a group like `Programmers` which includes 10 users.

I am using `Django Admin` to manage this.

thanks

Comment: uh... `from django.contrib.auth.models import Group` and then `group = models.ForeignKey(Group)`?

Comment: realy? that simple? :) thank you! you can post this as answer. so i can vote up and apply your answer! @yuvi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just link the model to the `Group` object, like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class Pm(models.Model):
    # ...
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

Small note: depending on your needs, it might be better to create your own User model with your own Group model. While these built-ins are great for out-of-the-box initialization, they're not very flexible, and are mostly aimed at managing the admin site.